# Checking for multiple IPs are online

Tags: vb.net

I currently have an application that pings around 50 pieces of equipment and displays a "Up" or "Down" arrow, depending if its online or not. The issue with it is, it pings one at a time, and that takes awhile. I want to see if there is a way to ping all of them at the same time, and display the results when they appear.

Example of current method:

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping(RouterBox.Text, 2000) Then
                'Online
                If GetPingMs(RouterBox.Text) < 125 Then
                    'Good ping
                    RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
                Else
                    'Bad ping
                    RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingHIGH
                End If
            Else
                'Offline
                RouterPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
            End If
```

Notes: I am running this within a Backgroundworker. This application is also a WinForm. Due to around 1000 lines of code currently for my current ping method, I would like to find a way that will not involve a entire rewrite (if possible).

Comment: Can't you just start multiple backgroundworkers? (1 for each IP for example?)

Comment: How about utilizing [**`System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendAsync()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144958(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @VisualVincent I have not looked into that, I am doing research now!

Comment: @VisualVincent I am looking into it, but it seems the MSDN has no examples, just the syntax. Any ideas for a simple example that can get me started?

Comment: Side note:  it would be better to load the images into an array and assign from there.  If there are 50 items UP you dont need to use 50 unique image objects which is what you are doing now.

Comment: @Plutonix Wow.... I deserve to rewrite my whole application for not doing that. Thanks man!

Comment: If you do it that way repeatedly on an interval, the way you are doing it there would require that you dispose of the old image to prevent leaking resources

Comment: `Any ideas for a simple example that can get me started?` - I can write an answer for you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a helper class that I've made for a simple implementation of your ping technique. It utilizes the [**`System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) and its [**`SendAsync()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxz6dah9(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform an asynchronous ping request.

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public NotInheritable Class PingHelper
    Private Sub New() 'Create no instances of this class.
    End Sub

    'Events.
    Public Delegate Sub RequestsCompletedEventHandler(SentRequests As Tuple(Of String, PictureBox)()) 'The event handler signature.
    Public Shared Event RequestsCompleted As RequestsCompletedEventHandler 'The event for when all requests are done.

    'Instances of the state images.
    Private Shared Online As Image = My.Resources.Online
    Private Shared Offline As Image = My.Resources.Offline
    Private Shared HighPing As Image = My.Resources.HighPing

    'SyncLock object.
    Private Shared SyncLockObj As New Object

    'Keeping track of the requests.
    Private Shared AddressRequests As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, PictureBox)) 'The addresses of all current requests + their assigned picture boxes.
    Private Shared CompletedRequests As Integer = 0 'Self explanatory.

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Asynchronously sends a ping request to the specified endpoint and changes the image of the StatePictureBox based on the reply.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Address">The IP-address or hostname to ping.</param>
    ''' <param name="Timeout">The maximum number of milliseconds to wait for a reply.</param>
    ''' <param name="StatePictureBox">The PictureBox which's image to change based on the reply.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Sub PingAsync(ByVal Address As String, ByVal Timeout As Integer, ByVal StatePictureBox As PictureBox)
        Using PingRequest As New Ping
            AddHandler PingRequest.PingCompleted, AddressOf PingRequest_PingCompleted 'Adds an event handler to the PingCompleted event.
            PingRequest.SendAsync(Address, Timeout, StatePictureBox) 'Start the asynchronous ping request.
            AddressRequests.Add(New Tuple(Of String, PictureBox)(Address, StatePictureBox)) 'Add the address to the list.
        End Using
    End Sub

    'Event handler for when a ping request has completed.
    Private Shared Sub PingRequest_PingCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventArgs)
        CompletedRequests += 1 'Increment the amount of completed requests.

        If CompletedRequests >= AddressRequests.Count Then 'Are all requests done?
            RaiseEvent RequestsCompleted(AddressRequests.ToArray()) 'All current requests are done, raise the RequestsCompleted event.

            'Reset the variables.
            AddressRequests.Clear()
            CompletedRequests = 0
        End If


        If e.UserState Is Nothing OrElse e.UserState.GetType() IsNot GetType(PictureBox) Then Return 'If UserToken is not a PictureBox do not continue execution.
        Dim StatePictureBox As PictureBox = DirectCast(e.UserState, PictureBox) 'Get the picture box which's image to change.

        SyncLock SyncLockObj 'SyncLock to fix concurrency issues.
            If e.Reply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then 'Ping succeeded.
                If e.Reply.RoundtripTime < 125 Then 'Is ping less than 125 ms?
                    StatePictureBox.Image = Online
                Else
                    StatePictureBox.Image = HighPing
                End If
            Else 'Ping failed, endpoint is not online or an error occurred.
                StatePictureBox.Image = Offline
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Note:** You have to change the `Online/Offline/HighPing` image variables to your own images.

You can use the `RequestsCompleted` event to indicate when all requests have been completed.

**Example usage:**

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler PingHelper.RequestsCompleted, AddressOf PingHelper_RequestsCompleted 'Subscribe to the "RequestsCompleted" event.
End Sub

Private Sub PingHelper_RequestsCompleted(SentRequests As Tuple(Of String, PictureBox)())
    Dim Message As String = String.Format("{0} requests completed:", SentRequests.Length) 'A message to display.
    For Each Request As Tuple(Of String, PictureBox) In SentRequests 'Iterate through all completed requests.
        Message &= Environment.NewLine & Request.Item1 'Add each IP-address/hostname on a new line in the message.
        'Request.Item1 = The address of the request.
        'Request.Item2 = The picture box which's image will be updated by the request.
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(Message, "Requests completed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) 'Display the message.
End Sub

Private Sub PingButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PingButton.Click
    'Send 10 ping requests to different endpoints.
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox1.Text, 2000, PictureBox1)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox2.Text, 2000, PictureBox2)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox3.Text, 2000, PictureBox3)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox4.Text, 2000, PictureBox4)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox5.Text, 2000, PictureBox5)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox6.Text, 2000, PictureBox6)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox7.Text, 2000, PictureBox7)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox8.Text, 2000, PictureBox8)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox9.Text, 2000, PictureBox9)
    PingHelper.PingAsync(TextBox10.Text, 2000, PictureBox10)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks perfect! I am going to play around with it now!

Comment: @dwb : Okay, good luck! Let me know if it works and/or you have any questions. :)

Comment: You sir, are my hero. It worked perfectly (had to make a few changes for my direct needs). I cannot express my gratitude for helping, and I feel like I learned something new with the help of your comments. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: One side question, how can I have the application wait until all results are returned before trying to do something else. IE, in your above example, wait till it is done with number 10 before doing something after.

Comment: @dwb : Give me a few minutes and I should be able to put something together. Do you want to wait for a specified amount of requests or do you want to specify an index?

Comment: The goal is have an option for live results. So if the user checks a box, it will ping all of the items, then when it has returned results for all of them, run another ping, ect.

Comment: @dwb : Okay, so I'll just make an event that will be raised once all ping requests have returned then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129475/discussion-between-dwb-and-visual-vincent).