# Keep a program running with windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to make a small program that will allow me to ping an ip address and login to an ssh section.

I want to be able to keep ping mutable ip address with out closing any of them.

I would like to do the same with the ssh sections. Right now I have to close cmd and then ping a different address.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ip As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Command As String
        Command = "putty.exe" & " " & "-ssh" & " " & "user" & "@" & ip & " " & "port" & " " & "-pw" & " " & "Password"
        Shell($"cmd /K{Command}", 1, True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim textvar As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim Command As String
        Command = "Ping" & " " & textvar & " " & "-t "
        Shell("cmd /k" & Command, 1, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: [**Ping it yourself?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40820084/3740093)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with your problem but may be able to help you clean up your code a bit.

Rather than using

```
& " " &
```

why don't you just put strings together with the spacing. It would then look like:
`Command = "putty.exe -sh user@" & ip & " port -pw Password"
        Shell($"cmd /K{Command}", 1, True)`

It does the exact same thing but doesn't have near as many characters and reads easier in my own humble opinion.