# Multiple IP pinging

Tags: vb.net

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.20.251") Then
     Console.WriteLine("IP FOUND")
Else
     Console.WriteLine("IP NOT FOUND")
End If
```

Is there a way to ping an array of IP address and display if how many is online and offline?

Comment: Yes. Put all your addresses into an array, and then loop through the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for multiple IPs are online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812993/checking-for-multiple-ips-are-online)

Comment: @PaulKaram that's too complicated. Im looking for an easy way to do that.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer will try that one. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I am new to VB. So probably I may not understand that easily. Anyways, thanks youuu

Comment: @PaulKaram I think you're replying to the wrong person.

Comment: I am sorry Andrew. @LjLj It might look complicated, but it certainly has much better performance than looping through a list of IPs synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider `ListOfIPs` is a `List(Of String)` or a string array that is already populated.

I can't clearly understand if you just want to the number of online IPs and offline. 
Here's a solution to do both: show which one is ON/OFF, and count them.

```
Dim IpIsOn as Integer = 0
Dim IpIsOff as Integer = 0

For Each ip as String in ListOfIPs
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(ip) Then
         Console.WriteLine(ip & " is online")
         IpIsOn = IpIsOn + 1
    Else
         Console.WriteLine(ip & " is offline")
         IpIsOff = IpIsOff + 1
    End If
Next

Console.WriteLine("A total of " & IpIsOn & " IP are online, while " & IpIsOff & " are offline.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done by putting the IP addresses that you want into an array and loop through that array and then test every IP.

Code (not tested, but should give you  the idea):

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.Add("192.168.20.251")
list.Add("192.168.233.1")
list.Add("192.168.0.199")
list.Add("192.168.2.55")


For Each item As String In list
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(item) Then Console.WriteLine("IP FOUND " + item) Else Console.WriteLine("IP NOT FOUND " + item) End If
Next
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and/or check the answer as the riught one.