# Ping multiple IP by a button click and change color to red if offline and green if online

Tags: vb.net, ping

This works fine for 10 IPs, but how to do it for 50+ IPs  without delay in win forms.

I am currently doing the ping via my.computer.network.ping(IP). The program execute one by one rather than simultaneous so the delay. I see several post of multi threading but no proper solution.

Scenario is i have multiple buttons, i give one subnet with 3 octet in a textbox and ping several ips by concat(textbox1.text+.1,.2,.3)

So the program is like this:

```
Private_button_click_event()
if my.computer.network.ping(Textbox1.text & ".1")then
   button1.backcolor=color.green
else
   button1.backcolor=color.red
end if

if my.computer.network.ping(Textbox1.text & ".2")then
   button2.backcolor=color.green
else
   button2.backcolor=color.red
end if
```

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40820084/3740093) might be of interest to you. Currently it works by changing the image of a picture box to an image identifying the endpoint as "Online", "Offline" or "High ping".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either parallelize it. To ping 50 ip addresses takes<20 sec on my pc using this ..

```
Private Sub PingThemAll()

    Parallel.For(1, 51, Sub(i As Integer)
                            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(TextBox1.Text & "." & i.ToString) Then
                                Me.Controls("button" & i).BackColor = Color.Green
                            Else
                                Me.Controls("button" & i).BackColor = Color.Red
                            End If
                        End Sub)
End Sub
```

However, the above will only run the same number of threads as you have cores in your cpu - I think.

or you could set up a new thread for each ping like below - It is slightly more complicated, but much quicker on my Pc and completed in a couple of seconds

```
Private Sub PingThemAllThreading()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        Dim th As New Thread(AddressOf PingOne)
        th.Start(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PingOne(i As Integer)
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(TextBox1.Text & "." & i.ToString) Then
        Me.Controls("button" & i).BackColor = Color.Green
    Else
        Me.Controls("button" & i).BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Me.Controls("xxx") is not valid; it gives a compile-time error.

Comment: @SezMe did you have 50 buttons created?

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the valuable commands. I do get it fast. The problem i see now is, the last octet, as the buttons i have is not sequential. Even if i make it sequential, the IP address is not going to be sequential. so i need to alter something here, but its pretty fast using multi thread. Please share me your thoughts.

Comment: If your button names are sequential as I assumed in my code, you could make a list of integers  to store the last octet, and use that instead of the loop index. If the button names aren't sequential, you could use a dictionary of String,Integer to store the button name and the octet you want it to refer to. The last approach could be risky if buttons were added, deleted, or had names changed of course.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for the note. is there any sample code for your above suggestion(for second approach). is there a way to click multiple labels at once using multi thread, so each label click event will in-turn have 10 IPs to ping. Like instead of doing ping of 50 IPs as 1*50, i am dividing 5*10 simultaneously

Comment: I'm not sure that would bring you any benefit. It may possibly be quicker in terms of the time it takes to initiate each ping request, but you will always be limited by the time it takes to complete the ping requests. It will of course be quicker if you're pinging addresses on your local LAN. The biggest thing that takes the time is if an address isn't pingable. By defaul `Ping` has a timeout of 500ms.

Comment: You could shorten this by adding a second parameter  .. `My.Computer.Network.Ping(TextBox1.Text & "." & i.ToString,200)` which would change the timeout to 200ms, but of course you would need to be certain that all the addresses would respond within that time.

Comment: Hi David,  If the button names aren't sequential, you could use a dictionary of String,Integer to store the button name and the octet you want it to refer to. The last approach could be risky if buttons were added, deleted, or had names changed of course. - could you please provide a sample code, i will use this way as the buttons and IP wont change.